# Looking for an illustrator script to export without anti-aliasing

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I'm looking for a workaround to export raster without anti-aliasing.

`ExportType.PNG 8/24` with `exportOptions.antiAliasing = false` export with anti-aliasing.

The only way I know is to export *manually* to BMP, but this isn't an option. I need strict bitmap colors in my files because of color-coding.

I already tried `app.activeDocument.rasterize`, but the script just stops after reaching this line.

Comment: I just tried [adobe-illustrator-rasterize-script](https://gist.github.com/tehmou/4492002) and it didn't work. I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS5.1 (15.1.0) for PC and now I'm very confused.

Comment: I found that argument for rasterize should be not selection but one object or group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full version of two functions for exporting color-coded zones without anti-aliasing.

The first of them adds recursively all visible objects (in all nested layers and groups) for further rasterization.

```
function process(item){
    if (item.layers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < item.layers.length; i++) {
            if(item.layers[i].visible) process(item.layers[i]);
        }
    }
    if (item.groupItems) {
        for (var i = 0; i < item.groupItems.length; i++) {
            if(! item.groupItems[i].hidden) process(item.groupItems[i]);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < item.pageItems.length; i++) {
        if (item.pageItems[i].typename != 'GroupItem') {
            array.push(item.pageItems[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is main export function. It processes array `z` (in my case I've prepared it first from specified layer: `var z = d.layers.getByName('/Zones')`) and export rasterized PNG file without anti-aliasing.

```
function saveZones(name){
    var exportPath  = '/Source/Zones/';
    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();
    var type = ExportType.PNG24;
    exportOptions.artBoardClipping = true;
    exportOptions.antiAliasing = false;
    exportOptions.transparency = false;
    exportOptions.saveAsHTML = false;

    var rasterizeOptions = new RasterizeOptions();
    rasterizeOptions.antiAliasingMethod = AntiAliasingMethod.None;
    rasterizeOptions.backgroundBlack = true;
    rasterizeOptions.clippingMask = false;
    rasterizeOptions.resolution = 72.0;
    rasterizeOptions.transparency = false;
    rasterizeOptions.convertSpotColors = true;

    var fileExport = new File(filePath+exportPath+name);
    var t = d.layers.add();
    t.name = 'tmp '+name;
    var tmpGroup = t.groupItems.add();
    array = [];
    process(z);
    for (var i = array.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        tmpSel = array[i].duplicate();
        tmpSel.moveToBeginning(tmpGroup);
    };
    tmpRast = d.rasterize(tmpGroup, d.artboardRect, rasterizeOptions);
    app.activeDocument.exportFile( fileExport, type, exportOptions );
    tmpRast.remove();
    t.remove();
}
```